# Error in Tkinter; TclError: missing newline on line...)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am really working with a bigger program in Tkinter but this code raises the same error:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title('ROOT')

root.configure(background='blue')
root.option_readfile('tkinter_style_sheet.txt')

Button(root, text='Press Me!' ).grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

The "tkinter_style_sheet.txt" in question, is a .txt file written in Notepad whith text as follows:

```
*font:          Times 8 bold

*Button*font:       Times 10 bold

*Button*borderwidth:3

*Button*relief: raised

*Button*width: 3

*Button*height: 1

*Button*pady:3
```

With the given text file and code, I receive the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/problem_with_tkinter.py", line 7, in <module>
        root.option_readfile('tkinter_style_sheet.txt')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 658, in option_readfile
        self.tk.call('option', 'readfile', fileName, priority)
TclError: missing newline on line 7
```

I don't understand the error, I tried adding a '\n' character at line 7 but, not surprisingly, it didn't solve the problem. Anyone having an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting a blank line at the end of the file?

Answer (score 1):

do this on line 7:

```
*font:Times 8 bold
*Button*font:Times 10 bold
*Button*borderwidth:3
*Button*relief: raised
*Button*width: 3
*Button*height: 1
*Button*pady:3
```

enter a newline after the end of the last line.